# Group by SQL query Beginner

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I have a problem with this query :

```
SELECT MAX(PL.BEST_RESULT), S.NAME, A.NAME
FROM PLAYS PL
    INNER JOIN ATHLETE A ON A.ID_ATHLETE = PL.ID_ATHLETE
    INNER JOIN SPORT S ON S.ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT
GROUP BY PL.ID_SPORT, S.NAME, A.NAME
```

It displays all the records of the table plays but I just want the maximum of `best_result` grouped by sport with the athlete name who owns the result. Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my query?

EDIT: I also want to display the athlete who owns the best_result.
 Here are the tables

```
PLAYS {ID_ATHLETE, ID_SPORT, BEST_RESULT}
SPORT {ID_SPORT, NAME}
ATHLETE {ID_ATHLETE, NAME}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope it is clearer. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns every unique combination of sport and athlete. You need to remove A.NAME from your GROUP BY and SELECT and then you will just have distinct Sports.

```
SELECT MAX(PL.BEST_RESULT), S.NAME
FROM PLAYS PL
    INNER JOIN SPORT S ON S.ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT
GROUP BY PL.ID_SPORT, S.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to have one Inner Join statement in there.

```
Select Max(PL.BEST_RESULT), S.NAME
FROM PLAYS PL
INNER JOIN SPORT S
    ON S.ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT
GROUP BY S.NAME
       ,PL.ID_SPORT
```

You were trying to get everything with your query.